# UI Events Lost in embedded COM Control

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-c++, c#-4.0, com

I have a custom UserControl made with C# WinForms that is exposed via COM to a C++ host app.  When I wrote and debugged the UserControl, I had a C# test app and made sure the application works from that perspective.  C# WinForms control in a C# WinForms environment has no problems.

When testing it through our C++ COM host application, UI events no longer work.  Interacting through the hosting C++ applications UI, I can set the properties and see the response in the hosted control.  However, when I click on a control the whole app freezes.  I've observed the behavior with:

- Buttons
- Tab Pages
- Check Boxes
- Value Up/Down
- Text Boxes

As long as I don't click on an active UI component in the hosted COM control, it behaves normally--until an event happens where the COM control needs to create a new tab page.

I've tried setting all kinds of break points, but it freezes before we get to the hosted COM control and the whole app is frozen.  The alternate COM control that is arguably more complicated doesn't seem to have this behavior.

Any clues what is going on?  I'm lost trying to figure out the problem.

---

**New Information**

The contents of the whole UserControl was in a TabControl with several tabs.  I created a single button outside the TabControl, and when that was clicked I could interact with the controls inside the TabControl on each of the pages that were defined when the ComControl was initialized.

However, If I create a new TabPage or instantiate a FolderBrowserDialog I'm right back to the old behavior.  So, how do I use TabPages and such safely from within a ComControl?

Comment: How is the COM control registered? I had a problem with my COM component not passing back events whenever I didn't register it with the /tlb option.  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/is/clr/thread/e3a3930f-fa50-4959-8d51-2e345a8214bf

Comment: It's registered with the TLB option.  I think it has to do with whatever the active window is, and the window for the embedded COM Control is different than the window for the C++ app.  It's tied to the TabControl and the fact that it only filters the events down to its child controls **if** it's in the active window.